# How to search a tree for a specific node class

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, tree, trie

I've got a tree which is populated by `Node` objects. Each node has an ArrayList which stores its children nodes as there can be an unspecified amount of children, unlike in a binary tree.

How can I traverse the tree to find a specific node if each node has a number of children, where each child has its own children in turn, and so on. I'm just looking for a generic way of doing this iteratively, for example using a function which searches through a node's arrayList (storing children), and each child's subsequent children's array lists too.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

This is what I've tried so far:

```
return 
(
    (StrangeNode)current.ChildrenList
        .SingleOrDefault(c => 
            c.GetType().Name.ToString().Equals("StrangeNode"))
).myArrayList;
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ This sounds like an attempt at getting SO to do your homework?

Comment: It's not homework actually, I'm trying to implement a tree which is to have a special type of node at certain points in the tree (i.e. a different class)

Comment: He didn't mean it literally, what have you tried?

Comment: This is what I've tried so far, but to no avail:

return ((StrangeNode)current.ChildrenList.SingleOrDefault(c => c.GetType().Name.ToString().Equals("StrangeNode"))).myArrayList;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iteratively you could do something like this:

```
List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
nodes.add( rootnode )

for (int i=0; i < nodes.count; i++)
{

Node currentNode = nodes[i];

//do the processing to check here

nodes.add(currentNode.children) //not 100% sure how to do this, but you get the idea

}
```

If you want it done recursily its just a depth-first, very easy.

Comment: I didn't fully understand this - what you're saying is that I add all children into an array and search that array for the 'strange' node?

Comment: That's about it. You check the current Node, and you shove the children into an array. Then you check the next node, and you put those children into the array too. In the end you'll have gone through all the children.

Comment: However, how would this take care of the children's children?

Comment: Of course it would. At first you'll have just the root node. Then you add the root's children. Then you go to the next node (Child 1) - and you add its' children - and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The two most obvious ways are a depth first search and a breadth first search.  You can find examples of both in any algorithms text book or online by searching for it.   You can implement that depth first search recursively in 3-10 lines of code.

Comment: I've updated my question with what I've tried so far. I'd like to do this iteratively if possible, rather than recursively.

Comment: what's the benefit of doing it iteratively?

Comment: No benefit really, I just never grasped recursion hehe.